# Dimension of vector space and span

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I have the following problem

[image]

a) I say that the vectors are linearly independent because they are not scalar multiples of each other.

b) This one I'm struggling with. How do I find the dimension of the vector space? Is it 3 dimension due to the fact that the vectors only have 3 coordinates? Is it so simple?

c) I'm not sure what to say here. I don't think it belongs belongs to the span. If this is true, can it be explained by the same reasoning as in a)?

Comment: two linearly independent vectors span a two-dimensional space, even if they live in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I didn't know that. My book doesn't discuss dimension of vector rooms that much.

Comment: You're welcome; by the way, in English, we say vector *spaces*, not *rooms*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These questions are related to the concept of a *subspace*.  The ambient space here is $\mathbb{R}^3$, but there are many subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

What are the subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$?  There are two trivial spaces.  The space consisting only of the vector $\langle 0, 0, 0\rangle$ is a zero-dimensional subspace and the whole of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a three dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  The other subspaces are one and two dimensional.

The usual way to define a subspace is to specify a *spanning set*, that is, a set of vectors.  If $S$ is a set of vectors, then the spanning set of $S$, usually denoted $\textrm{span}(S)$, is the set of all vectors that can be written as linear combinations of elements of $S$.

In this case, you want to know the dimension of $\textrm{span}\left(\left\{\vec{a_1}, \vec{a_2}\right\}\right)$.

It can't be zero dimensional because it contains non-zero vectors.  And it can't be three dimensional (or higher) because there is a spanning set with two elements.

Could this subspace be one dimensional?  It it were there would have to be a single vector $\vec{x}$ that spanned the whole subspace.  But that would mean that there would be (non-zero) scalars $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ such that:

- $\lambda_1\vec{x}=\vec{a_1}$
- $\lambda_2\vec{x}=\vec{a_2}$

But then we could write $$\frac{1}{\lambda_1}\vec{a_1} - \frac{1}{\lambda_2}\vec{a_2}=\mathbf{0}$$ which would imply that $\vec{a_1}$ and $\vec{a_2}$ are not linearly independent,  contradicting your answer to question 1.

All of this is a roundabout way to get to the conclusion that if $S$ is a finite set of linearly independent vectors, then $$\dim(\textrm{span}(S))=\vert S\vert.$$

For part 3, you already have the right idea. To show that $\vec{a_1}$ is not in $\textrm{span}(\{\vec{a_2}\})$, you just need to show that there is no $\lambda$ such that $\lambda\vec{a_2}=\vec{a_1}$, which will follow directly from the fact that $\vec{a_1}$ and $\vec{a_2}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you so much for a great explanation! It was really helpful to understand dimensions of vector rooms :)

Answer (score 2):

Answering each of your questions:

**a)** True, they are linearly independent (it's easily seen that they're not schalar multiples of each other). You can see this from noticing that in the second component, $a_1$ has $-1$ and $a_2$ has $1$, but the other components aren't the same with opposite symbols.

**b)** Since they are linearly independent, then the vector space generated by both vectors (or how it's written: $\langle a_a,a_2\rangle$) is of dimension $2$ (it would have been dimension $1$ if they were linearly dependent).

**c)** Since $a_1$ is not a schalar multiple of $a_2$ (because they are linearly independent), you conclude that $a\notin \langle a_2\rangle$.

As you see, all of your questions have to do with the same important question: are those vectors linealy independent? The answer to that is yes, and the following statements are concluded from there.

Comment: Thank you for answering all of my questions! I like the useful information you give at the end there. I have never thought about that before. Thank you again :)

Comment: @Mathomat55 you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

$a)$ For the vectors to be independent, the relationship $\lambda_{1}a_1+\lambda_{2}a_2=0 $

must yield $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$.

You can verify that this is the case here.

$b)$ You have two linearly independent vectors. This means that any $v \in V$, where $V$ is the vector space created by $a_1, a_2$ can be written as their linear combination. That is, $v=\kappa_1a_1+\kappa_2a_2$.

Now all you have to do is (re)check the definitions found on your course notes/book to see if it holds true.. Same for $c)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help :)

Answer (score 1):

B) Let $W=span(a_1,a_2)$. $\dim(W)=2$. In fact the dimension of a subaspace is the cardinality of a basis. In this case, since $a_1$ and $a_2$ are generators(by definition) of the subspace, and are linearly indpendent they are a basis

C)If $\; a_1 \in span(a_2) \Rightarrow a_1=ka_2$, which is not true.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see now that my reasoning about a 3-dimensional space was wrong. Thank you for correcting me! :)